# R create factor based on condition

Tags: r, type-conversion

I need to change a column from numeric to factor based on the numeric value being higher or lower than 10.

For example with the following data:

```
age <- c(1:20)
hight <- c(1:20)
d.frame <- data.frame(age, hight)
```

I tried the following:

```
d.frame$hight <- factor(d.frame$hight, levels( 1:9, 10:max(d.frame$hight) ), labels=c('low','high'))
```

and

```
d.frame$hight <- factor(d.frame$hight, levels( <10, >=10) ), labels=c('low','high'))
```

But don't work.

Any ideas now to do this type conversion?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We could use `cut` to change the `numeric` to `factor` column based on the condition

```
d.frame$hight <- cut(d.frame$hight, breaks = c(-Inf, 10, Inf), 
             labels = c('low', 'high'), right = FALSE)
```

---

As there are only two levels, another option would be to create a logical vector and use `ifelse` to change the values

```
d.frame$hight <- factor(ifelse(d.frame$hight>=10, "high", "low"))
```

Comment: What if I have more than 2 levels, like 0-7, 7-15 and 15-20, and I cannot use cut because input is not numeric ?

Comment: @DanChaltiel  It is not clear.  Please post a new question.

Comment: :-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44285151/how-to-separate-a-vector-based-on-conditions-in-r